# Radio button in mobile theme Prestashop not working

Tags: php, html, css, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have Prestashop 1.6 and using the default theme called default-bootstrap.

In mobile devices, the radio buttons when selecting product attributes (for example size/colour etc) on product page do not work. The problem occurs only on mobile devices and only with this theme (with another theme they work). 
When tapping the product attribute, the URL bar is changed, but the selection of attribute doesn't change (and if added to cart, the wrong selection remains).

For example in this page: http://clubvapea.es/gb/e-liquids/182-full-month-pack-4-x-mix-of-avoria-12ml-german-e-liquid-valeo.html

This is added to the end of the URL: #/90-avoria-nicotina9mg

But in mobile devices nothing happens.
What is the problem?
Thank you for your help!

My themes/default-bootstrap/product.tpl

```
SKIPPED TO FIRST PLACE WHERE ATTRIBUTE IS SHOWN AS THE CODE IS TOO LONG
        <!-- pb-right-column-->
        <div class="pb-right-column col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            {if ($product->show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode)) || isset($groups) || $product->reference || (isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS)}
            <!-- add to cart form-->
            <form id="buy_block"{if $PS_CATALOG_MODE && !isset($groups) && $product->quantity > 0} class="hidden"{/if} action="{$link->getPageLink('cart')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" method="post">
                <!-- hidden datas -->
                <p class="hidden">
                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$static_token}" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="{$product->id|intval}" id="product_page_product_id" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="id_product_attribute" id="idCombination" value="" />
                </p>
                <div class="box-info-product">
                    <div class="content_prices clearfix">
                        {if $product->show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode) && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                            <!-- prices -->
                            <div>
                                <p class="our_price_display" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">{strip}
                                    {if $product->quantity > 0}<link itemprop="availability" href="http://schema.org/InStock"/>{/if}
                                    {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
                                        <span id="our_price_display" class="price" itemprop="price">{convertPrice price=$productPrice}</span>
                                        {if $tax_enabled  && ((isset($display_tax_label) && $display_tax_label == 1) || !isset($display_tax_label))}
                                            {if $priceDisplay == 1} {l s='tax excl.'}{else} {l s='tax incl.'}{/if}
                                        {/if}
                                        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{$currency->iso_code}" />
                                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
                                    {/if}
                                {/strip}</p>
                                <p id="reduction_percent" {if !$product->specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'percentage'} style="display:none;"{/if}>{strip}
                                    <span id="reduction_percent_display">
                                        {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'percentage'}-{$product->specificPrice.reduction*100}%{/if}
                                    </span>
                                {/strip}</p>
                                <p id="reduction_amount" {if !$product->specificPrice || $product->specificPrice.reduction_type != 'amount' || $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval ==0} style="display:none"{/if}>{strip}
                                    <span id="reduction_amount_display">
                                    {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction_type == 'amount' && $product->specificPrice.reduction|floatval !=0}
                                        -{convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction-$productPrice|floatval}
                                    {/if}
                                    </span>
                                {/strip}</p>
                                <p id="old_price"{if (!$product->specificPrice || !$product->specificPrice.reduction) && $group_reduction == 0} class="hidden"{/if}>{strip}
                                    {if $priceDisplay >= 0 && $priceDisplay <= 2}
                                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="old_price"}
                                        <span id="old_price_display">{if $productPriceWithoutReduction > $productPrice}<span class="price">{convertPrice price=$productPriceWithoutReduction}</span>{if $tax_enabled && $display_tax_label == 1} {if $priceDisplay == 1}{l s='tax excl.'}{else}{l s='tax incl.'}{/if}{/if}{/if}</span>
                                    {/if}
                                {/strip}</p>
                                {if $priceDisplay == 2}
                                    <br />
                                    <span id="pretaxe_price">{strip}
                                        <span id="pretaxe_price_display">{convertPrice price=$product->getPrice(false, $smarty.const.NULL)}</span> {l s='tax excl.'}
                                    {/strip}</span>
                                {/if}
                            </div> <!-- end prices -->
                            {if $packItems|@count && $productPrice < $product->getNoPackPrice()}
                                <p class="pack_price">{l s='Instead of'} <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">{convertPrice price=$product->getNoPackPrice()}</span></p>
                            {/if}
                            {if $product->ecotax != 0}
                                <p class="price-ecotax">{l s='Including'} <span id="ecotax_price_display">{if $priceDisplay == 2}{$ecotax_tax_exc|convertAndFormatPrice}{else}{$ecotax_tax_inc|convertAndFormatPrice}{/if}</span> {l s='for ecotax'}
                                    {if $product->specificPrice && $product->specificPrice.reduction}
                                    <br />{l s='(not impacted by the discount)'}
                                    {/if}
                                </p>
                            {/if}
                            {if !empty($product->unity) && $product->unit_price_ratio > 0.000000}
                                {math equation="pprice / punit_price"  pprice=$productPrice  punit_price=$product->unit_price_ratio assign=unit_price}
                                <p class="unit-price"><span id="unit_price_display">{convertPrice price=$unit_price}</span> {l s='per'} {$product->unity|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</p>
                                {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="unit_price"}
                            {/if}
                        {/if} {*close if for show price*}
                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="weight"}
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div> <!-- end content_prices -->
                    <div class="product_attributes clearfix">
                        <!-- quantity wanted -->
                        {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                        <p id="quantity_wanted_p"{if (!$allow_oosp && $product->quantity <= 0) || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                            <label>{l s='Quantity'}</label>
                            <input type="text" name="qty" id="quantity_wanted" class="text" value="{if isset($quantityBackup)}{$quantityBackup|intval}{else}{if $product->minimal_quantity > 1}{$product->minimal_quantity}{else}1{/if}{/if}" />
                            <a href="#" data-field-qty="qty" class="btn btn-default button-minus product_quantity_down">
                                <span><i class="icon-minus"></i></span>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" data-field-qty="qty" class="btn btn-default button-plus product_quantity_up">
                                <span><i class="icon-plus"></i></span>
                            </a>
                            <span class="clearfix"></span>
                        </p>
                        {/if}
                        <!-- minimal quantity wanted -->
                        <p id="minimal_quantity_wanted_p"{if $product->minimal_quantity <= 1 || !$product->available_for_order || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} style="display: none;"{/if}>
                            {l s='The minimum purchase order quantity for the product is'} <b id="minimal_quantity_label">{$product->minimal_quantity}</b>
                        </p>
                        {if isset($groups)}
                            <!-- attributes -->
                            <div id="attributes">
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                {foreach from=$groups key=id_attribute_group item=group}
                                    {if $group.attributes|@count}
                                        <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
                                            <label class="attribute_label" {if $group.group_type != 'color' && $group.group_type != 'radio'}for="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}"{/if}>{$group.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}&nbsp;</label>
                                            {assign var="groupName" value="group_$id_attribute_group"}
                                            <div class="attribute_list">
                                                {if ($group.group_type == 'select')}
                                                    <select name="{$groupName}" id="group_{$id_attribute_group|intval}" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
                                                        {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                                            <option value="{$id_attribute|intval}"{if (isset($smarty.get.$groupName) && $smarty.get.$groupName|intval == $id_attribute) || $group.default == $id_attribute} selected="selected"{/if} title="{$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</option>
                                                        {/foreach}
                                                    </select>
                                                {elseif ($group.group_type == 'color')}
                                                    <ul id="color_to_pick_list" class="clearfix">
                                                        {assign var="default_colorpicker" value=""}
                                                        {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                                            {assign var='img_color_exists' value=file_exists($col_img_dir|cat:$id_attribute|cat:'.jpg')}
                                                            <li{if $group.default == $id_attribute} class="selected"{/if}>
                                                                <a href="{$link->getProductLink($product)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" id="color_{$id_attribute|intval}" name="{$colors.$id_attribute.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" class="color_pick{if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} selected{/if}"{if !$img_color_exists && isset($colors.$id_attribute.value) && $colors.$id_attribute.value} style="background:{$colors.$id_attribute.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'};"{/if} title="{$colors.$id_attribute.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                                                    {if $img_color_exists}
                                                                        <img src="{$img_col_dir}{$id_attribute|intval}.jpg" alt="{$colors.$id_attribute.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$colors.$id_attribute.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="20" height="20" />
                                                                    {/if}
                                                                </a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)}
                                                                {$default_colorpicker = $id_attribute}
                                                            {/if}
                                                        {/foreach}
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <input type="hidden" class="color_pick_hidden" name="{$groupName|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" value="{$default_colorpicker|intval}" />
                                                {elseif ($group.group_type == 'radio')}
                                                    <ul>
                                                        {foreach from=$group.attributes key=id_attribute item=group_attribute}
                                                            <li>
                                                                <input type="radio" class="attribute_radio" name="{$groupName|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" value="{$id_attribute}" {if ($group.default == $id_attribute)} checked="checked"{/if} />
                                                                <span>{$group_attribute|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</span>
                                                            </li>
                                                        {/foreach}
                                                    </ul>
                                                {/if}
                                            </div> <!-- end attribute_list -->
                                        </fieldset>
                                    {/if}
                                {/foreach}
                            </div> <!-- end attributes -->
                        {/if}
                    </div> <!-- end product_attributes -->
                    <div class="box-cart-bottom">
                        <div{if (!$allow_oosp && $product->quantity <= 0) || !$product->available_for_order || (isset($restricted_country_mode) && $restricted_country_mode) || $PS_CATALOG_MODE} class="unvisible"{/if}>
                            <p id="add_to_cart" class="buttons_bottom_block no-print">
                                <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="exclusive">
                                    <span>{if $content_only && (isset($product->customization_required) && $product->customization_required)}{l s='Customize'}{else}{l s='Add to cart'}{/if}</span>
                                </button>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        {if isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS}{$HOOK_PRODUCT_ACTIONS}{/if}
                    </div> <!-- end box-cart-bottom -->
                </div> <!-- end box-info-product -->
            </form>
            {/if}
        </div> <!-- end pb-right-column-->
    </div> <!-- end primary_block -->
    {if !$content_only}
{if (isset($quantity_discounts) && count($quantity_discounts) > 0)}
            <!-- quantity discount -->
            <section class="page-product-box">
                <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Volume discounts'}</h3>
                <div id="quantityDiscount">
                    <table class="std table-product-discounts">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>{l s='Quantity'}</th>
                                <th>{if $display_discount_price}{l s='Price'}{else}{l s='Discount'}{/if}</th>
                                <th>{l s='You Save'}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {foreach from=$quantity_discounts item='quantity_discount' name='quantity_discounts'}
                            <tr id="quantityDiscount_{$quantity_discount.id_product_attribute}" class="quantityDiscount_{$quantity_discount.id_product_attribute}" data-discount-type="{$quantity_discount.reduction_type}" data-discount="{$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}" data-discount-quantity="{$quantity_discount.quantity|intval}">
                                <td>
                                    {$quantity_discount.quantity|intval}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {if $quantity_discount.price >= 0 || $quantity_discount.reduction_type == 'amount'}
                                        {if $display_discount_price}
                                            {convertPrice price=$productPrice-$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}
                                        {else}
                                            {convertPrice price=$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}
                                        {/if}
                                    {else}
                                        {if $display_discount_price}
                                            {convertPrice price = $productPrice-($productPrice*$quantity_discount.reduction)|floatval}
                                        {else}
                                            {$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}%
                                        {/if}
                                    {/if}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span>{l s='Up to'}</span>
                                    {if $quantity_discount.price >= 0 || $quantity_discount.reduction_type == 'amount'}
                                        {$discountPrice=$productPrice-$quantity_discount.real_value|floatval}
                                    {else}
                                        {$discountPrice=$productPrice-($productPrice*$quantity_discount.reduction)|floatval}
                                    {/if}
                                    {$discountPrice=$discountPrice*$quantity_discount.quantity}
                                    {$qtyProductPrice = $productPrice*$quantity_discount.quantity}
                                    {convertPrice price=$qtyProductPrice-$discountPrice}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {/foreach}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </section>
        {/if}
        {if isset($features) && $features}
            <!-- Data sheet -->
            <section class="page-product-box">
                <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Data sheet'}</h3>
                <table class="table-data-sheet">
                    {foreach from=$features item=feature}
                    <tr class="{cycle values="odd,even"}">
                        {if isset($feature.value)}
                        <td>{$feature.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                        <td>{$feature.value|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</td>
                        {/if}
                    </tr>
                    {/foreach}
                </table>
            </section>
            <!--end Data sheet -->
        {/if}
        {if $product->description}
            <!-- More info -->
            <section class="page-product-box">
                <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='More info'}</h3>{/if}
                {if isset($product) && $product->description}
                    <!-- full description -->
                    <div  class="rte">{$product->description}</div>
            </section>
            <!--end  More info -->
        {/if}
        {if isset($packItems) && $packItems|@count > 0}
        <section id="blockpack">
            <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Pack content'}</h3>
            {include file="$tpl_dir./product-list.tpl" products=$packItems}
        </section>
        {/if}
        <!--HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB -->
        <section class="page-product-box">
            {$HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB}
            {if isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB_CONTENT) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB_CONTENT}{$HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB_CONTENT}{/if}
        </section>
        <!--end HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB -->
        {if isset($accessories) && $accessories}
            <!--Accessories -->
            <section class="page-product-box">
                <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Accessories'}</h3>
                <div class="block products_block accessories-block clearfix">
                    <div class="block_content">
                        <ul id="bxslider" class="bxslider clearfix">
                            {foreach from=$accessories item=accessory name=accessories_list}
                                {if ($accessory.allow_oosp || $accessory.quantity_all_versions > 0 || $accessory.quantity > 0) && $accessory.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
                                    {assign var='accessoryLink' value=$link->getProductLink($accessory.id_product, $accessory.link_rewrite, $accessory.category)}
                                    <li class="item product-box ajax_block_product{if $smarty.foreach.accessories_list.first} first_item{elseif $smarty.foreach.accessories_list.last} last_item{else} item{/if} product_accessories_description">
                                        <div class="product_desc">
                                            <a href="{$accessoryLink|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$accessory.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" class="product-image product_image">
                                                <img class="lazyOwl" src="{$link->getImageLink($accessory.link_rewrite, $accessory.id_image, 'home_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" alt="{$accessory.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"/>
                                            </a>
                                            <div class="block_description">
                                                <a href="{$accessoryLink|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='More'}" class="product_description">
                                                    {$accessory.description_short|strip_tags|truncate:25:'...'}
                                                </a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="s_title_block">
                                            <h5 itemprop="name" class="product-name">
                                                <a href="{$accessoryLink|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                                    {$accessory.name|truncate:20:'...':true|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                                                </a>
                                            </h5>
                                            {if $accessory.show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode) && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                                            <span class="price">
                                                {if $priceDisplay != 1}
                                                {displayWtPrice p=$accessory.price}{else}{displayWtPrice p=$accessory.price_tax_exc}
                                                {/if}
                                            </span>
                                            {/if}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="clearfix" style="margin-top:5px">
                                            {if !$PS_CATALOG_MODE && ($accessory.allow_oosp || $accessory.quantity > 0)}
                                                <div class="no-print">
                                                    <a class="exclusive button ajax_add_to_cart_button" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, "qty=1&amp;id_product={$accessory.id_product|intval}&amp;token={$static_token}&amp;add")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" data-id-product="{$accessory.id_product|intval}" title="{l s='Add to cart'}">
                                                        <span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                            {/if}
                                        </div>
                                    </li>
                                {/if}
                            {/foreach}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            <!--end Accessories -->
        {/if}
        {if isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_FOOTER) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_FOOTER}{$HOOK_PRODUCT_FOOTER}{/if}
        <!-- description & features -->
        {if (isset($product) && $product->description) || (isset($features) && $features) || (isset($accessories) && $accessories) || (isset($HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB) && $HOOK_PRODUCT_TAB) || (isset($attachments) && $attachments) || isset($product) && $product->customizable}
            {if isset($attachments) && $attachments}
            <!--Download -->
            <section class="page-product-box">
                <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Download'}</h3>
                {foreach from=$attachments item=attachment name=attachements}
                    {if $smarty.foreach.attachements.iteration %3 == 1}<div class="row">{/if}
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <h4><a href="{$link->getPageLink('attachment', true, NULL, "id_attachment={$attachment.id_attachment}")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$attachment.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></h4>
                            <p class="text-muted">{$attachment.description|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</p>
                            <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" href="{$link->getPageLink('attachment', true, NULL, "id_attachment={$attachment.id_attachment}")|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                <i class="icon-download"></i>
                                {l s="Download"} ({Tools::formatBytes($attachment.file_size, 2)})
                            </a>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    {if $smarty.foreach.attachements.iteration %3 == 0 || $smarty.foreach.attachements.last}</div>{/if}
                {/foreach}
            </section>
            <!--end Download -->
            {/if}
            {if isset($product) && $product->customizable}
            <!--Customization -->
            <section class="page-product-box">
                <h3 class="page-product-heading">{l s='Product customization'}</h3>
                <!-- Customizable products -->
                <form method="post" action="{$customizationFormTarget}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="customizationForm" class="clearfix">
                    <p class="infoCustomizable">
                        {l s='After saving your customized product, remember to add it to your cart.'}
                        {if $product->uploadable_files}
                        <br />
                        {l s='Allowed file formats are: GIF, JPG, PNG'}{/if}
                    </p>
                    {if $product->uploadable_files|intval}
                        <div class="customizableProductsFile">
                            <h5 class="product-heading-h5">{l s='Pictures'}</h5>
                            <ul id="uploadable_files" class="clearfix">
                                {counter start=0 assign='customizationField'}
                                {foreach from=$customizationFields item='field' name='customizationFields'}
                                    {if $field.type == 0}
                                        <li class="customizationUploadLine{if $field.required} required{/if}">{assign var='key' value='pictures_'|cat:$product->id|cat:'_'|cat:$field.id_customization_field}
                                            {if isset($pictures.$key)}
                                                <div class="customizationUploadBrowse">
                                                    <img src="{$pic_dir}{$pictures.$key}_small" alt="" />
                                                        <a href="{$link->getProductDeletePictureLink($product, $field.id_customization_field)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Delete'}" >
                                                            <img src="{$img_dir}icon/delete.gif" alt="{l s='Delete'}" class="customization_delete_icon" width="11" height="13" />
                                                        </a>
                                                </div>
                                            {/if}
                                            <div class="customizationUploadBrowse form-group">
                                                <label class="customizationUploadBrowseDescription">
                                                    {if !empty($field.name)}
                                                        {$field.name}
                                                    {else}
                                                        {l s='Please select an image file from your computer'}
                                                    {/if}
                                                    {if $field.required}<sup>*</sup>{/if}
                                                </label>
                                                <input type="file" name="file{$field.id_customization_field}" id="img{$customizationField}" class="form-control customization_block_input {if isset($pictures.$key)}filled{/if}" />
                                            </div>
                                        </li>
                                        {counter}
                                    {/if}
                                {/foreach}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                    {if $product->text_fields|intval}
                        <div class="customizableProductsText">
                            <h5 class="product-heading-h5">{l s='Text'}</h5>
                            <ul id="text_fields">
                            {counter start=0 assign='customizationField'}
                            {foreach from=$customizationFields item='field' name='customizationFields'}
                                {if $field.type == 1}
                                    <li class="customizationUploadLine{if $field.required} required{/if}">
                                        <label for ="textField{$customizationField}">
                                            {assign var='key' value='textFields_'|cat:$product->id|cat:'_'|cat:$field.id_customization_field}
                                            {if !empty($field.name)}
                                                {$field.name}
                                            {/if}
                                            {if $field.required}<sup>*</sup>{/if}
                                        </label>
                                        <textarea name="textField{$field.id_customization_field}" class="form-control customization_block_input" id="textField{$customizationField}" rows="3" cols="20">{strip}
                                            {if isset($textFields.$key)}
                                                {$textFields.$key|stripslashes}
                                            {/if}
                                        {/strip}</textarea>
                                    </li>
                                    {counter}
                                {/if}
                            {/foreach}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                    <p id="customizedDatas">
                        <input type="hidden" name="quantityBackup" id="quantityBackup" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="submitCustomizedDatas" value="1" />
                        <button class="button btn btn-default button button-small" name="saveCustomization">
                            <span>{l s='Save'}</span>
                        </button>
                        <span id="ajax-loader" class="unvisible">
                            <img src="{$img_ps_dir}loader.gif" alt="loader" />
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </form>
                <p class="clear required"><sup>*</sup> {l s='required fields'}</p>
            </section>
            <!--end Customization -->
            {/if}
        {/if}
    {/if}
```

ALSO SKIPPED SOME CODE FROM THE END AS IT IS TOO LONG

Comment: post the code and then we;ll help you

Comment: Show us your product.tpl https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/themes/default-bootstrap/product.tpl

Comment: Do you have the latest release of this theme? You may also try to change your radio button to drop-down list until we find the problem: https://www.prestashop.com/forums/uploads/monthly_01_2015/post-535854-0-81380200-1421522770.png

Comment: Thank you for the replies! My product.tpl looks following:

Comment: anyone out there? :)

Answer (score 0):

Radio button works. The problem in styles. More precisely - in the used classes.
Selector "**div.radio span**" should be replaced by "**div.radio div.radio span**" in the file *themes\THEME\css\autoload\uniform.default.css* in lines 12, 194 and 196.

12:

```
div.selector, div.selector span, div.checker span, div.radio span, div.uploader, div.uploader span.action, div.button, div.button span {
```

to

```
div.selector, div.selector span, div.checker span, div.radio div.radio span, div.uploader, div.uploader span.action, div.button, div.button span {
```

194:

```
div.radio span.checked {
    background-position: -13px -243px; }
```

to

```
div.radio div.radio span.checked {
```

196:

```
div.radio input {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1;
    text-align: center; }
```

to

```
div.radio div.radio input {
```